# The first homology group $H_1(M)$ of a compact manifold $M$ is always $\mathbb Z_i \oplus \mathbb Z_j\oplus...\oplus\mathbb Z_n$ ($i,j,...,n\ge 2 $)?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

- The dimension of the first homology group $H_1(M)$ is the number of (nonequivalent) loops of the manifold $M$.
- For all the cases I know, such as $RP^n$, $S^n$, cylinder, n-torus, klein bottle and so on, $H_1$ seems always be $ G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus...\oplus G_n$, where $G_i$ is $\mathbb Z_m$($m \geq 2 $) or $\mathbb Z$, where $i\in$ {$1,..,n$} .
- Or trivial $H_1(M)=0$.

My Question(**updated** due to the comments below)?

- Is the conclusion correct for **all compact manifolds**? ($H_1(M)$ means with $\mathbb Z$ coefficient).
- If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your notation, this is already wrong for $S^1$, since $H_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Thanks for pointing it out, I was thinking infinite dim means $\mathbb Z$, but indeed it is not correct. I've revised the notation.

Comment: This is wrong as well. Any countable group is the fundamental group of a manifold, for example $\mathbb{Q}$. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192230/is-there-a-manifold-with-fundamental-group-mathbbq

Comment: The conclusion is correct when $M$ is compact.

Comment: @Thorgott thanks for the comments, I've revised the question. If we only consider compact manifolds.

Comment: Well, there's two parts to this: 1.) $H_1(M)$ is a finitely generated abelian group, 2.) Classification of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: In fact all homology groups $H_k(M)$ of a compact manifold are finitely generated abelian groups, not just $H_1(M)$.